# react-router-dom: How to match urls with some pattern

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I have urls like

```
/detail/sbc-123
/detail/tresds-121212
/detail/xywh-1
```

How to write the router for this and get the string `sbc-123`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options by [docs](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks/useroutematch)

```
import { Route } from "react-router-dom";

function App() {
  return (
    <Route
      path="/detail/:exact"
      render={({ match }) => {
        /* Do whatever you want with the match... */
        return <div />;
      }}
    />
  );
}


// Or you can just
import { useRouteMatch } from "react-router-dom";

function Component() {
  let match = useRouteMatch("/detail/:exact");

  // Do whatever you want with the match...
  return <div />;
}
```

a match object contains useful information the given argument is its path and you can access the correct path via the URL field

```
match.path // '/details/:exact'
match.url // '/detail/sbc-123'
```